# set min value yAxes using pimeng Chart

Tags: angular, bar-chart, primeng

I´m using primeng to visualize a diagram with angular but the min value of the y-axis does not work. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

barComponent.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: "app-grafica-bar",
templateUrl: "./grafica-bar.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./grafica-bar.component.css"]
})
export class GraficaBarComponent implements OnInit {
data: any;
options: any;

constructor() {
    this.data = {
        labels: [
            "Enero",
            "Febrero",
            "Marzo",
            "Abril",
            "Mayo",
            "Junio",
            "Julio",
            "Agosto",
            "Septiembre",
            "Octubre",
            "Noviembre",
            "Diciembre"
        ],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Descargas',
                backgroundColor: ['#16d24a', '#2ece47', '#40cb44', '#5ac640', '#6ac43e', '#75c23c', '#16d24a', '#3fb37b', '#28ad97', '#1aa9a8', '#02a3c3', '#02a3c3'],
                data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 10, 55, 65, 59, 80, 81, 56] 
            }
        ]
    }

    this.options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: {
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ngOnInit() {};
}
```

The result obtained is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o34zd.png)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!!

```
this.options = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
               ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  suggestedMax: 100, 
               }
            }] 
        }  
    }
```